# TakeUntil not working as documented?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

From [the docs for the `TakeUntil` operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/takeuntil.html) (emphasis mine):

> The TakeUntil subscribes and begins mirroring the source Observable. It also monitors a second Observable that you provide. If this second Observable emits an item **or sends a termination notification**, the Observable returned by TakeUntil stops mirroring the source Observable **and terminates**.

If this is true, then why does this block?:

```
Observable.Never<Unit>()
    .TakeUntil(Observable.Empty<Unit>())
    .Wait();
```

Comment: Take from a non-terminating sequence until an empty sequence emits an item.  That sounds like it should block indefinitely.

Comment: Why would you think this would throw an exception instead of waiting forever?

Comment: @juharr: You're right in that no items are emitted, but `Empty()` should **send a termination notification** right away, should it not?

Comment: @seldon OK, I see what you mean now. `TakeUntil` should see that the second sequence has terminated and thus return a terminated sequence and the `Wait` shouldn't block, but I don't see any reason for an exception.

Comment: @juharr: Right! The exception is just an unimportant detail. `Wait()` semantics are similar to `First()`. No items in the sequence will raise an exception. I'll remove that part in order to not draw focus away from the real issue.

Comment: fwiw, the (old) [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229530(v=vs.103).aspx) is different than the main Rx site's and only states that `TakeUntil` "Returns the values from the source observable sequence until the other observable sequence produces a value." without considering terminated observables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preston Guillot is on point in the comments section:

> The (old) [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229530(v=vs.103).aspx) is different than the main Rx site's, and only states that `TakeUntil` *"Returns the values from the source observable sequence until the other observable sequence produces a value."* without considering terminated observables.

Let's take a [look at the source code](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/7d0f0c6b6c11f77817e6eb4c76295973e9dceb94/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Linq/Observable/TakeUntil.cs#L114) for `Observable.TakeUntil`, specifically `class O` which represents the "terminator" `Observable`. We can see that `parent.OnCompleted` notification is sent on `O.OnNext` and `O.OnError`.

So the reason why your code is blocking, is that `Observable.Empty` (which acts as the "terminator") emits only an `OnCompleted` notification.

Comment: Time for to submit a PR!

Comment: @LeeCampbell or is it? :) If an `Observable` only completes, does the user of `TakeUntil` want to stop or continue taking values from underlying `Observable`? I would argue this is by design and suits the operator well.

Comment: It _probably_ is by design, as most of these bugs were sorted after v1. However, from the point of view of this post, it does not meet the design of least surprise principal. :-) ...and it doesn't match the `ReactiveX` docs. Would be interesting to know the rationale behind the design.

Comment: Should we use `this.destroy$.next()` and `this.destroy$.complete()` in `ngOnDestroy()` when using `takeUntil`?