# How do I prematurely terminate an observable chain using TakeUntil?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I currently have the following:

```cs
var disconnect = Observable
    .FromEvent<ExceptionListener, Exception>(
        (handler) => connection.ExceptionListener += handler,
        (handler) => connection.ExceptionListener -= handler
    )
    .Do((exception) =>
    {
        // note: This line does get executed when I trigger the error scenario,
        //       so I know it is in fact happening.
        //
        Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
    });

var messages = Observable
    .Using(
        () => connection.CreateSession(),
        (session) => Observable
    .Using(
        () => session.GetQueue(address),
        (queue) => Observable
    .Using(
        () => session.CreateConsumer(queue),
        (consumer) => Observable
            .FromEvent<MessageListener, IMessage>(
                (handler) => consumer.Listener += handler,
                (handler) => consumer.Listener -= handler
            )
            .TakeUntil(disconnect)
    )))
```

Whenever I build on or otherwise subscribe to `messages`, it seems like the `TakeUntil` is not being honoured and the chain isn't aborted, even though `disconnect` does in fact seem to emit.

Ideally I'd like for this `IObservable` (or any resultant one that builds on it) to complete/terminate (I'm not sure what the right word is here) as soon as the `disconnect` observable emits.

For completeness, my consuming code is effectively:

```cs
await messages.ForEachAsync(async (message) =>
{
    // note: Do things with `message`
}, cancellationToken);

// note: During normal operation, this never gets run. But I want the await 
//       above to complete when my `TakeUntil` above emits.
Console.WriteLine("Chain completed/terminated.");
```

Comment: Could you check this variant of `disconnect`, to see if it makes any difference? `var disconnect = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));`

Comment: Doesn't appear to be triggered.  I tacked a `.Do` onto there just to see if the timer was ever happening. Is it possible that the `TakeUntil` is working, but just not terminating the observable, and thus never causing my `LastOrDefaultAsync` to ever complete? That doesn't explain why the `.Do` isn't called though...

Comment: The whole purpose of the `TakeUntil` is to terminate an observable, so I wouldn't expect it to fail on its sole mission! Is it possible that there is any forgotten `Repeat` after the `TakeUntil`?

Comment: I haven't added any `Repeat` calls yet. This one goes until the first thing that fails.

Comment: You could also experiment with this version of `messages`: `var messages = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).TakeUntil(disconnect);` Maybe this will help reveal the true cause of the problem.

Comment: So I'm pretty sure `TakeUntil` isn't terminating the observable: https://gist.github.com/atrauzzi/66e6fee81f80d5d0fed4d432f37c48b2 -- When I await in the second observable, control is never returned back.

Comment: Possibly relevant? -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35417909/takeuntil-not-working-as-documented

Comment: I put the [gist](https://gist.github.com/atrauzzi/66e6fee81f80d5d0fed4d432f37c48b2) in an `async Task Main` and it produced the expected result. Did you tested it with an `async void` method?

Comment: I'm calling it from inside an `async Task`, should be fine?

Comment: It depends on how this `async Task` is called! If it's called by an `async void` (directly or anywhere in the stack above), then it is the same as being `async void` itself.

Comment: Btw be aware of one difference between `Observable.FromEvent` and `Observable.Interval`. The former produces a hot observable, while the later produces a cold observable. This means that all subscribers of the `Observable.FromEvent` will observe the same sequence of events, while every subscriber of the `Observable.Interval` will observe a different sequence of generated values (the generator is started at the moment of subscription). I don't know if this difference has any relevance with the issue at hand. I assume that most probably it's not relevant.

Comment: Regarding the [possibly relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35417909/takeuntil-not-working-as-documented) question, it refers to observables that terminate without producing any value. The `Observable.FromEvent` normally never terminates, so I don't think that it's relevant.

Comment: You could try adding a buffer and a default value to the `disconnect` observable, in order to exclude the possibilities of either terminating without producing a value, or producing a single value before the creation of the `messages` observable: `.Replay(1).AutoConnect(0).DefaultIfEmpty()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working perfectly fine as it is. Here's how I tested it.

First up I got your original code into a compilable and runnable state.

```
public delegate void ExceptionListener();
public delegate void MessageListener();

public interface IMessage
{
    
}

public static class connection
{
    public static event ExceptionListener ExceptionListener;
    public static Session CreateSession() => new Session();
}

public class Session : IDisposable
{
    public Queue GetQueue(string address) => new Queue();
    public Consumer CreateConsumer(Queue queue) => new Consumer();
    
    #region IDisposable Support
    private bool disposedValue = false; // To detect redundant calls

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
            }

            // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override a finalizer below.
            // TODO: set large fields to null.

            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    // TODO: override a finalizer only if Dispose(bool disposing) above has code to free unmanaged resources.
    // ~Session() {
    //   // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
    //   Dispose(false);
    // }

    // This code added to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
        Dispose(true);
        // TODO: uncomment the following line if the finalizer is overridden above.
        // GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    #endregion

}

public class Queue : IDisposable
{

    #region IDisposable Support
    private bool disposedValue = false; // To detect redundant calls

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
            }

            // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override a finalizer below.
            // TODO: set large fields to null.

            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    // TODO: override a finalizer only if Dispose(bool disposing) above has code to free unmanaged resources.
    // ~Queue() {
    //   // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
    //   Dispose(false);
    // }

    // This code added to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
        Dispose(true);
        // TODO: uncomment the following line if the finalizer is overridden above.
        // GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    #endregion

}

public class Consumer : IDisposable
{
    public event MessageListener Listener;

    #region IDisposable Support
    private bool disposedValue = false; // To detect redundant calls

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
            }

            // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override a finalizer below.
            // TODO: set large fields to null.

            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    // TODO: override a finalizer only if Dispose(bool disposing) above has code to free unmanaged resources.
    // ~Consumer() {
    //   // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
    //   Dispose(false);
    // }

    // This code added to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
        Dispose(true);
        // TODO: uncomment the following line if the finalizer is overridden above.
        // GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Now I can run this code:

```
var address = "";

var disconnect =
    Observable
        .FromEvent<ExceptionListener, Exception>(
            handler => connection.ExceptionListener += handler,
            handler => connection.ExceptionListener -= handler)
        .Do(exception => Console.WriteLine(exception.Message));

var messages =
    Observable.Using(
        () => connection.CreateSession(),
        session => Observable.Using(
            () => session.GetQueue(address),
            queue => Observable.Using(
                () => session.CreateConsumer(queue),
                consumer =>
                    Observable
                        .FromEvent<MessageListener, IMessage>(
                            handler => consumer.Listener += handler,
                            handler => consumer.Listener -= handler)
                        .TakeUntil(disconnect))));
```

Then I refactored to avoid the events and to use a couple of `Subject<T>` instances to mock the events:

```
var address = "";

var disconnectSubject = new Subject<Exception>();

var disconnect =
    disconnectSubject
        .Do(exception => Console.WriteLine(exception.Message));

var messageSubject = new Subject<IMessage>();

var messages =
    Observable.Using(
        () => connection.CreateSession(),
        session => Observable.Using(
            () => session.GetQueue(address),
            queue => Observable.Using(
                () => session.CreateConsumer(queue),
                consumer => messageSubject.TakeUntil(disconnect))));
```

Now I can run this code:

```
messages.Subscribe(m => Console.WriteLine("Message"));

messageSubject.OnNext(null);
messageSubject.OnNext(null);
messageSubject.OnNext(null);
disconnectSubject.OnNext(new Exception());
messageSubject.OnNext(null);
```

The output I get is:

```
Message
Message
Message
Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
```

The `messages` observable is indeed ending when the `disconnect` subject fires.

Then I replaced my simple `messages.Subscribe` code with this:

```
var cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();
var task =
    messages
        .ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default)
        .ForEachAsync(async (message) =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
            Console.WriteLine("Message");
        }, cancellationToken);
```

I now get:

```
Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
Message
Message
Message
```

Apart from the change of output order produced by the `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));` nothing has changed here.

The `messages` observable ends in both cases, as expected.

Your code, as presented here, works just fine.

Comment: Yeah, I had assumed that the issue was within the portions that I shared.  I'm now trying to troubleshoot some parts I was - mistakenly - a little more certain of.  Particularly some `Catch()` calls on my observer chain.

Comment: @AlexanderTrauzzi - That's why a [mcve] is useful. Can you try to post one? If you can, please add it at the end of your existing question.

Comment: I know what you're saying, but that's kind of a chicken/egg suggestion.  If I knew where any issue was originating from, I'd for sure provide a reduced example.  Although by that same point, if I knew where it was, I'd probably be able to fix it myself.  This is probably the one thing about rxnet that I get tripped up by: debugging behaviour.

Comment: I think I've narrowed down one of my issues however and was able to distill it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64932766/how-do-i-multiplex-catch-so-that-it-doesnt-terminate-my-observable

Comment: @AlexanderTrauzzi - And that's part of the point of creating a [mcve] - often you will end up solving it yourself by trying to go through that exercise. And that's why you've come here, to solve the problem. It's worth doing it.

Comment: Again, it's a balancing act. Creating the isolated scenario often requires familiarity. Create a reproducible example, but one that also includes the nuance of the error, but not so much nuance as to offend.  We all do what we can, and I'm no beginner dev. I'm just here to ask questions about an API that I'm still learning and I'm sure working the process out here will help others in the future. Regardless of the source of the issue (me )!

Comment: @AlexanderTrauzzi - Fair enough.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is probably with how the observable is consumed:

```
await messages.ForEachAsync(async (message) =>
{
    // note: Do things with `message`
});
```

The [`ForEachAsync`](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/main/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Linq/Observable.Imperative.cs) operator does not accept an asynchronous delegate (`Func<Task>`), so the lambda passed is [`async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void) (also known as fire-and-crash). If you want to invoke an asynchronous lambda for each element of an observable sequence, you must use a projection to create an `IObservable<Task<T>>`, and then use one of the three flattening operators (`Concat`, `Merge` or `Switch`) to get back an `IObservable<TResult>` containing the results of the asynchronous invocations. If these don't have results, you can return something dummy like the `Unit.Default`.

```
await messages.Select(async message =>
{
    // note: Do things with `message`
    return Unit.Default;
}).Merge().DefaultIfEmpty();
```

The `DefaultIfEmpty` is there just to prevent an `InvalidOperationException` in case the sequence completes with zero messages.

---

Example with cancelable lambda:

```
await messages.Select(message => Observable.FromAsync(async cancellationToken =>
{
    // note: Do things with `message`, while observing the cancellationToken
    return Unit.Default;
})).Merge().DefaultIfEmpty();
```

Comment: Is there any way I can also fit in a cancellation token with your solution?

Comment: @AlexanderTrauzzi yes, using the `Observable.FromAsync`. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: Ah, my apologies.  I already have a cancellation token that I'd like to have used by the observable (updated my question).  Still possible?

Comment: @AlexanderTrauzzi essentially you want to convert a cancellation token to an observable, so that you can chain a second `TakeUntil` to observe it. I don't know if there is anything built-in. Here is a custom way to do it: `.TakeUntil(new Task(() => { }, someToken).ToObservable())`

Comment: Ah, interesting!  I'm just putting together all your suggestions, thank you so much.  I also like how `LastOrDefaultAsync` kind of makes sense when I think about my chain.

Comment: @AlexanderTrauzzi the RX team should consider adding a `TakeUntil` overload that accepts a `CancellationToken`. It seems like a useful feature. 

Comment: Totally agree, I might open a feature request 

Comment: Hmm, although all this being said, my observable still isn't finishing up when I trigger my original `TakeUntil` stream.

Comment: @AlexanderTrauzzi yeah, I wasn't sure either whether my suggestion would solve your problem. My guess is that something else is going on, in some other part of the program. Could you update your question with a reproducible example?

Comment: It's fairly involved with two different libraries. Again, I'm definitely seeing the `Console.WriteLine` inside of the `Do` I showed above.  So the rest of the program is working.  As is my observable which does successfully process data.  Really I just want a way to terminate it when `TakeUntil` happens.