# How do I multiplex Catch so that it doesn't terminate my observable?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Given [the following as a starting point](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ocn58F):

```cs
using System;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive;
using System.Threading;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Observable
            .Range(0, 3)
            .Select((iteration) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    if (iteration == 2)
                    {
                        throw new Exception();
                    }

                    return "Success!";
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Caught!");
                    
                    return "Exception!";
                }
            })
            .Do((message) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("After: " + message);
            })
            .RunAsync(new CancellationToken())
            .Wait();
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can adapt the above to leverage the `Catch` operator such that the 2nd iteration won't cause the entire chain to fail?  Perhaps using `SelectMany` or `Select` and `Merge`?

Comment: Are you sure it fails? AFAICS the observable completes successfully.

Comment: Yeah, I know that this works.  My question is, can this be *adapted* to use Catch operators.

Comment: So you want exactly the same behavior, but with a different implementation that uses the `Catch` operator? Could I ask out of curiosity why you want this?

Comment: My hope was for consistency in syntax by leveraging all of rx.

Comment: The `Catch` operator operates on faulted sequences. It concatenates a second sequence after a failed one. So in order to use this operator you must allow your sequence to fail, and then continue with a new sequence that contains all the elements that were not emitted by the first sequence. Things can get messy. I don't think that the `Catch` buys you anything in this case.

Comment: That's valuable insight!  Are there any alternatives that might do what I want?  Again, what if I were to multiplex the operations (`Select`/`SelectMany`), use `Catch` and the `Merge` them? Could that prevent them from terminating the stream?

Comment: I think it would be better if you could construct a specific scenario that includes these operators (Select/SelectMany/Merge), to make it easier for us to offer suggestions with some rationale and justification behind them.

Comment: I agree, but that's assuming I know how to use them properly and then I'd be able to answer my own question. :D

Comment: Yes, indeed. This should be your goal though. To reach an experience level that you can [answer your own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), and use the StackOverflow as an extension of your memory. 

Comment: Hmm, apologies but I feel you're being a bit pedantic with that.  SO is somewhere people should feel comfortable asking questions and I think my question is pretty clear.  The example is runnable.  I'm really just asking a question about syntax and would love to get an answer.

Comment: Alexander I am sorry about that. I was just trying to be funny. Please ignore my previous comment.

Comment: Why did put a `.RunAsync(new CancellationToken())` in your pipeline? It's doing nothing, afaics.

Comment: @Enigmativity the OP is probably using a real (cancelable) `CancellationToken` in their actual application, as a mechanism for canceling the sequence.

Comment: Yeah, I just needed something to show that the `RunAsync` was there.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - As a way to cancel the `Wait()` - Urrrghh...

Comment: That `Wait` is there just because I didn't do an `async Main` in the fiddle.